# Javascript with PHP combination

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php script that returns an echo of 'Hello' when accessed half the time (just based on a random number).

Is it possible to make a javascript script on a HTML page that will:

Go to the the PHP page,

If 'Hello' is returned it will show an alert of 'Goodbye'

ELSE

It shows 'nothing found'

**What do I need to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called AJAX. Example:

```
var msg = 'Nothing found';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    alert(xhr.responseText != "Hello" ? msg : "Goodbye");
  }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

See also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to use jQuery and Ajax to fetch the page.

```
       $.ajax({ 
       type:"GET", 
       url:"file.php", 
       data:id, // if you want to pass a param, optional
       success:function(data){ 
          alert(data);//do something with data
       }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the information is not very confidential, I can suggest you to use **Cookies** (in case you don't want to use AJAX, but I still recommend you to use AJAX). People don't usually take the advantage of Cookies.

So, in PHP file, set the Cookies with your information:

```
$value = 'Hello';
setcookie("Information", $value);
```

And get it from HTML using Javascript (from [W3School](http://w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp))

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just include the page in an iframe (with or without a meta-refresh) and instead of echoing 'hello' you would echo the javascript alert ;)